# How to correctly update kubernetes api-server.yaml manifest file for hardening and sweet32

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes, redhat

I'm attempting to update the `/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml` as well as the `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml` manifest to mitigate the SWEET32 vulnerability. From reading the documents and various other pages it appears that updating the files with tls cipher suite list should correct the issue however whenever I make the change on the `api-server.yaml` file the api-server container never comes up after a kubelet restart.

How should this update be done? via yaml file editing or is there a command line config?

config.yaml has the following appended to the file:

```
tlsCipherSuites: ["TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256","TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256","TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305","TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384","TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305","TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384","TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384","TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256"]
```

The kube-apiserver.yaml file is updated with:
spec:
containers:

command:

```
    - --tls-cipher-suites=TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
```

Answer (score 0):

These ciphers should fix all sweet32 issues.

```
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
```

Same can be used for kube-apiserver, kube-controller-manager, kube-scheduler, kubelet and etcd as well to mitigate issues for all components.

Edit the respective yaml and pass these for the following argument

```
--tls-cipher-suites=$ABOVE_TLS_CIPHER_SUITES
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, i've made the changes however it seems the same error persists, 
Aug 13 19:06:57 <hostname> kubelet[20653]: E0813 19:06:57.630275   20653 kubelet.go:2268] node "<hostname>" not found

Comment: have you checked your /etc/hosts file with right hostname?